# Stuck with a complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Happy New Year 2014 to all StackOverFlow contributors and users.

I have searched and gone through the available topics similar to mine. But, failed to find that satisfies my requirements. Hence, posting it here.

I have four tables: "Organization", "Members", "Resource" and "member-resource"

The schema can be found here at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7eafb9/2)

I want to find out the number of distinct `res_name` from `Resource` table that have more than one `res_prop` for each organizations. Expected output would be as follows:

```
| org_id       | res_count      |
| 2            | 4              |
| 3            | 1              |
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: The same assignment as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865436/mysql-query-for-solving-a-specific-issue/20865802#comment31306680_20865802). Why don't you stuck to previous question?

Comment: Because that one is kept on hold. I dont know why.

Comment: Your question was put on hold for a reason, you should not be reposting the question to bypass this. Fortunately for you someone has fed you the answer before this one gets put on hold too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT org_id,count(DISTINCT res_name) as res_count
FROM
(SELECT o.org_id,r.res_name,COUNT(DISTINCT res_prop)as distinct_res_prop
FROM organization o
INNER JOIN members m USING (org_id)
INNER JOIN `member-resource` mr USING (mem_id)
INNER JOIN resource r USING (res_id)
GROUP BY o.org_id,r.res_name
HAVING COUNT(distinct_res_prop) > 1
 )T1
GROUP BY org_id
```

In HAVING clause add COUNT

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7eafb9/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. It works perfectly alright. I owe you for your assistance.